# using c and tcl , error when getting data from file with Tcl_GetVar2

Tags: c, tcl

what is the best way of using Tcl_GetVar2 in c ?

```
 axes   = (Axes*)   malloc(sizeof(Axes));
  axes->Xorientation = Tcl_GetVar2(interp, "axes", "XOrientation", TCL_GLOBAL_ONLY);
```

with axes as the structure

```
typedef struct {
    double XvaleurMin;
    double XvaleurMax;
    double XRatio;
    char *Xorientation;
    double YvaleurMin;
    double YvaleurMax;
    double YRatio;
    char *Yorientation;
  } Axes;
```

This is example is getting errors in execution when parsing a data file with missings data.

for example Segmentation fault when doing

```
printf("axes->Yorientation %s\n",axes->Yorientation );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `Tcl_GetVar2` API function *does* return a `char *`, you need to remember that Tcl retains ownership of that pointer: it can and will deallocate it at a time of its choosing, possibly on the next API call you make. Also, you really ought to treat it as `const char *`; don't modify that string either (there are some historical reasons for us not making that `const`). If you want to keep it around, you need to copy it immediately and that will entail some work with buffer management, with there being many ways to achieve it.

Or alternatively you might be able to use `Tcl_GetVar2Ex`, which returns a `Tcl_Obj *`, a Tcl native value reference. With those, you *can* keep them around (as long as you remember to `Tcl_IncrRefCount` them when you do so and `Tcl_DecrRefCount` them once you no longer need it) and you can then get the `char *` (though still not something you should modify) from that value reference at any time using `Tcl_GetString` or `Tcl_GetStringFromObj` (the latter also reports the number of bytes in the string).

---

If you are really interested in parsing the value to mean some sort of string chosen from a small set — the sort of thing I'd expect when parsing an “orientation” attribute of some kind — I strongly suggest looking at `Tcl_GetIndexFromObj`. That's explicitly designed for that sort of task, handling a great many aspects for you that are normally an annoying amount of fiddly work to get right for yourself.